# Iterate over a list and strip tags in text from nested tags with scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm testing scrapy and can't figure out how to retrieve plain text without tags in it when it is nested in tags. Here is the URL I test it on:
http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293915-i3686-k8824646-What_s_the_coolest_thing_you_saw_or_did_in_Thailand-Thailand.html

Desired output:
[content of the posts as separate elements in the item[body] object](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/566667/ad8bba1f52835dbe8c32c575913e0c39)

My code:

```
import scrapy

from tripadvisor.items import TripadvisorItem

class TripadvisorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
[...]

def parse_thread_contents(self, response):
    url = response.url
    item = TripadvisorItem()
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="balance"]'):
        item['body'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="postBody"]//p').extract()
    yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `text()` of the `p` elements. There is also a problem in the loop - you need to iterate over posts one by one and get the post bodies and collect them in a list:

```
item['body'] = ["".join(post.xpath('.//div[@class="postBody"]/p/text()').extract()) 
                for post in response.xpath('//div[@class="postcontent"]')]
```

Also note that the dot at the beginning of the expression is also important - it would make the search *context-specific*.

Demo:

```
In [1]: for post in response.xpath('//div[@class="postcontent"]'):
   ...:     print("".join(post.xpath('.//div[@class="postBody"]/p/text()').extract()))
   ...:      
What's that memory you'll carry forever with you? Maybe you stayed on a floating hut in Khao Sok Lake, or you washed elephants in a sanctuary, or....I have no idea. Please share if you like, I'd love to hear!
The heat when you you go to  for the first time, my blessing ceremony with my husband on Bottle Beach is up there, as is the first time I met him in Samui. Phang Nga Bay on the west coast is stunning and took my breath away, I overnighted on a friend's boat and watched the stars come out. Hong Island was amazing and arriving at Koh Racha before it had hotels on it. Early morning mist on the river at Amphawa whilst looking across to a beautiful temple, the Chao Praya River in Bangkok, the Reclining Buddha at Wat Pho - I could go on and on. : )
First trip to  few years back. Not very informed, no smart phone, no google earth....rent a bike, with my wife and we just ride the bike "till the road ends"...ended up at their local uni, watch student going in and out of the uni gate, sat on the road side having a coke. No worries...just me and my wife.Cassnu, pls...go on and on...we dont mind.
...
```

Comment: Indeed it does strip the tags and I thank you for that, but I'd also like to separate each reply in a separate string element of the list.
With this, it will join every reply together in a very long string

Comment: @fassn please use the updated code (sorry for multiple edits).

Comment: No worries, thanks for your quick replies. :)

Thanks for the explanations, now I also understand what I did wrong with the loop by not looking into each post separately.

But still, the json output I get only keeps the latest post in the item['body'] object. Not sure to understand how to make it append each content body as a new element of a list.
The output I get is: 
`body": "Arriving at Phi Phi island from  by ferry on my 1st trip was amazing"`
I'm running the spider using the 'scrapy crawl spider_name -o item.json' command

Comment: @fassn sure, we can use a list comprehension, updated.

Comment: awesomesauce, you rock! :D It works like a charm.
And gives me food for thought about this damn list-comprehension I don't master yet. :)

Have a nice week-end